# how to stop ajax call in live highcharts when no new data

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts

I am using the live update version of highcharts framework
with an update on my database 
I want to know if there is method that give me alert when no new data is added to the chart.
The ajax call is already stopped when no new data is inserted on my DB

```
                  function requestData() {
            $.ajax ({
            type:"get" ,
    url: "<?php echo 
             CController::createUrl('sens/GetSensorsDataLive') ?>",

            data: {"sensId" : "<?php echo $modelsens['node_id'] ?>" },
               dataType: "json",

             success: function(point) {

          var series = chart.series[0],


          shift = series.data.length > 25 ;
               chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point),true, shift); // add the point
              setTimeout(requestData,1000);    // call it again after one second
    /// what I should add here 

                                   },

         cache: false
       });

      }
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it runs `success` ? When you get some error you should run `error`.
So, call `requestData` on `error` too.

```
success: function(point) {

    var series = chart.series[0],

    shift = series.data.length > 25 ;
    chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point),true, shift); // add the point
    setTimeout(requestData,1000);    // call it again after one second
},

error: function() {
    alert('no data');
    setTimeout(requestData,1000);
}
```

Comment: thanks ricardo,yes every thing is ok, when all point are retrieved from database (no new insert in database) so I get the error in firebug  and my chart stop updating. where can I add the request data on error ?

Comment: many thanks, now the ajax call dont stop when getting error in firebug (Trying to get property of non-object) but how I display alert when there is no data.

Comment: @user1425371 Add an `alert` before call requestData.

Answer (score 0):

Well it should check if your data has length, so if is empty then you can set data as null in Highcharts.

Comment: thanks sebastien, I do some computation to retrieve data so when there is no data the ajax call stop because the server return 0 (error in firebug) ca I for example make an alert when there is no data added after 5 second from last point ? thanks again